# Can I regularly log ship from a source to a target, while running DML on the target?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, log-shipping, reporting

I want to have two databases on separate severs. Let's call the databases Source and Target. Target is the reporting server copy of Source. Except for the changes caused by a stored procedure that I need to regularly run in Target, I want Source and Target to be identical and sync'd up roughly once a day. All of the data needed to create Source comes from the same server as Source.

Is log shipping a suitable method to solve this problem? Or does my "I need to run a stored procedure that changes database Target" restriction completely rule that out?

Comment: What part of "[Supports limited read-only access to secondary databases (during the interval between restore jobs).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#benefits)" is unclear? 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Except for the changes caused by a stored procedure that I need to regularly run in Target, I want Source and Target to be identical and sync'd up roughly once a day.

> Is log shipping a suitable method to solve this problem?

Nope. Log shipping creates a **read-only** replica on the subscriber / target side. See the [docs Erik linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#benefits) for more information.

> Or does my "I need to run a stored procedure that changes database Target" restriction completely rule that out?

Correct. See [Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver16) for a native SQL Server feature that allows the subscriber / target database to be changed and written to.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> Except for the changes caused by a stored procedure that I need to regularly run in Target

Target database could be open only read-only so stored procedure cannot modify anything in Target database. However stored procedure can modify data in other databases.